# Add compose to project on offline mode failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-android-extensions

I download all `compose` libraries and add jar files to libs directory then add them to the gradle correctly. my kotlin version is 1.6.10, I set `composeOptions { kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0-beta03' }`
and then I build project. gradle get error of `No cached version of androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0-beta03 available for offline mode`, but that library jar file added correctly. what is the problem? also I have no access to internet and I should use offline mode only.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue.
The below steps worked for me:

Step 1. Add compose libraries in online mode.

Step 2. Clean, Rebuild and Run the project in online mode. Please make sure everything works fine.

Step 3. Invalidate and restart in online mode.

Step 4. Clean, Rebuild and Run the project in online mode. Please make sure everything works fine.

Step 5. Now you can set toggle offline mode.

This worked in my case.